# Cannot import python standard library modules - ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, importerror

I'm using Windows 10, Python 3.11.2, VS Code. When importing some of Python Standard Library modules, e.g.:

```
from collections import deque
```

I get the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\Karenin\Documents\IStudy> & C:/Users/Karenin/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe c:/Users/Karenin/Documents/IStudy/bt.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Karenin\Documents\IStudy\bt.py", line 1, in <module>
    from collections import deque
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

Pylint says:

```
Cannot import 'collections' due to 'invalid or missing encoding declaration for 'C:\\Users\\Karenin\\Documents\\IStudy\\collections.py''Pylint(E0001:syntax-error)
```

I got the same behavior when importing re:

```
import re
```

But this happens not for all modules. For instance, such modules as math, itertools, etc. are imported correctly. If I remove/comment the import string and the respective function call in the code, the rest works fine.

Default and current file encoding is set to UTF-8. I tried running the same code in PyCharm. Tried reinstalling Python 3.11.2, using Python 3.10.10. Nothing works.
However, the same imports do work correctly in Python REPL.
Any ideas of how can I fix it?

Comment: Do note that you have a `collections.py` module (`C:\\Users\\Karenin\\Documents\\IStudy\\collections.py`) that's shadowing the standard library `collections` module. It's your `collections.py` module that misbehaving. Appearntly that file has a null byte in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you place check mark in install pip ?

Comment: Thank you, Edward. Renaming my local file (collections.py) did the trick! Resaving another file (with "import re", where were copy-pasted code snippets) with UTF-8 encoding also worked. How could I be so unattentive and spent so much time and efforts struggling with the problem, while the solution was obvious and on the surface!
I didn't understand you question about check mark. What do you mean?

Comment: check mark in install pip when you install python. that's what I meant